# In HTML, if I have one img positioned behind another, how do I make it not take up twice the room?

Tags: html, css

If I have the one image, my positioning is fine. However, if I add the second one behind it (`position: relative` and `z-index` applied) the positioning gets skewed and it seems that the div takes up more room than it had before (they're both positioned within the same div).

They're both the same size.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="resume-header">
    <a href="resume.pdf">
        <img src="media/resume-icon.png" alt="Resume icon" title="Download resume (PDF)" class="top-image" style="position:relative;z-index:2;">
        <img src="media/resume-icon-download.png" style="position:relative;right:132px;z-index:1;visibility:hidden;"><br>
        <span class="center-text">Resume (PDF)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Possibly relevant CSS:

```
.resume-header {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 130px;
    text-align: center;
}

.resume-header a {
    color: #333;
    font: 10px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

Comment: using position:relative; tells the element to position itself relative to the other relatively positioned elements nearby, which is why it won't sit directly behind it UNLESS one of the elements is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use `z-index` you should be using `position: absolute` to position your elements.